# Oracle installation: Missing Dependency: elfutils-libelf-devel and elfutils-libelf-devel-static

Tags: oracle

At the time of installing "elfutils-libelf-devel" and "elfutils-libelf-devel-static" package (which are required for oracle installation) I found these below error:

**Missing Dependency: elfutils-libelf-devel-i386 = 0.137-3.el5 is needed by package elfutils-libelf-devel-static-0.137-3.el5.i386 (/elfutils-libelf-devel-static-0.137-3.el5.i386)**

**Missing Dependency: elfutils-libelf-devel-static-i386 = 0.137-3.el5 is needed by package elfutils-libelf-devel-0.137-3.el5.i386 (/elfutils-libelf-devel-0.137-3.el5.i386)**

I am using Linux Red Hat Enterprise Edition 5 and the pre-req package installed in my system is: elfutils-libelf-0.137-3.el5.

***[oracle@oratst ~]$ rpm -qa elfutils-libelf*
elfutils-libelf-0.137-3.el5***

Please suggest me the exact package name or any link from where I can download these package and install.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this link : https://community.oracle.com/thread/2576757

Comment: Did you install glibc.386 on you 64 bit system?
If no, please do that.